# get keys and values from a Python dictionary as lists

Tags: python, list

I have the following output from a code I ran on Python:

```
T1 =  [{0: 0}, {15: 3}, {19: 1}, {20: 1}, {0: 0}]
```

I want to extract the keys and values from each object respectively. For T1, I would thus have:

```
P1 =  [0,15,19,20,0]
D1 = [0, 3, 1,1,0]
```

What would be the best way to code it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: How did you end up with such a list in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the questions. While I am not new in Python, I kept applying the same logic  I use with Stata to extract the desired data, which caused me to get the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`List Comprehensions`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
In [148]: P1 = [list(i.keys())[0] for i in T1]

In [149]: D1 = [list(i.values())[0] for i in T1]

In [150]: P1
Out[150]: [0, 15, 19, 20, 0]

In [151]: D1
Out[151]: [0, 3, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good case for [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> from operator import methodcaller

>>> T1 =  [{0: 0}, {15: 3}, {19: 1}, {20: 1}, {0: 0}]

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(T1))
[0, 15, 19, 20, 0]

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(methodcaller('values'), T1)))
[0, 3, 1, 1, 0]
```

A dictionary when iterated over yields its keys; `chain.from_iterable` takes a list of such iterables and yields all their keys in a sequence. To do the same with the values, call `values()` on each item, for which we `map` a `methodcaller` here (equivalent to `(i.values() for i in T1)`).

Answer (score 1):

this should work:

```
T1 = [{0: 0}, {15: 3}, {19: 1}, {20: 1}, {0: 0}]

P1 = [next(iter(dct)) for dct in T1]
D1 = [next(iter(dct.values())) for dct in T1]
```

you take the first element ([`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next)) of an iterator over the keys (`iter(dct)`) or an interator over the values (`iter(dct.values()`).

this will not create any unnecessary lists.

or in one go (note: these return `tuples` not `lists`):

```
P1, D1 = zip(*(next(iter(dct.items())) for dct in T1))
```

or (using parts of [deceze's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66741671/4954037)):

```
from itertools import chain

P1, D1 = zip(*chain.from_iterable(dct.items() for dct in T1))
```

Comment: You can replace the list comprehension with a generator expression (`[]` → `()`) for even more efficiency in that `zip` approach.

Comment: @deceze aaargh! of course. thanks! (and there i was claiming that no additional lists are created...) i like your version too!